# I'm using the formula below and want to find the length of γ

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to find the length of the smooth curve $γ(t)$ from $t = 0$ to $t = \pi/4$

I'm using the formula for γ:
$$l(γ) = \int_a^b|\gamma'(t)|\,dt$$
apologies I can't work out how to format that correctly.

I have $ \gamma'(t) $
I am now aware this is incorrect but am struggling to amend it myself
I'm not sure how to apply this into the formula without it just integrating back into its original form?

Any help or identification of areas where I've made a mistake would be really useful.

Comment: Your computation of the derivative is not correct.

Comment: Please look up Mathjax, to format your equations

Comment: Thanks for responding, whereabouts have I made the error?

Comment: How do you get $\sin(it+1)$? Or $\cos(t-i)$?

Comment: I used the derivative of γ(t)

Comment: What's mean $\sin\color{red}{t}(t)$? This seems to be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $$\gamma(t)=e^{it}+t(\sin(t)-i\cos(t))=e^{it}+t\sin(t)-it\cos(t)$$
so, you have that $$\gamma'(t)=\color{blue}{ie^{it}}+\sin(t)+t\cos(t) +it\sin(t)-i\cos(t). \quad [1]$$
Now, since that for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $$e^{it}=\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$$
The, you can re-write $[1]$ as $$\gamma'(t)=\sin(t)+t\cos(t)\color{blue}{-\sin(t)}+it\sin(t)-i\cos(t)\color{blue}{+i\cos(t)}.$$
Using that for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$ we have that $$|z|=\sqrt{\operatorname{Re}(z)^{2}+\operatorname{Im}(z)^{2}}$$
So, you have that \begin{eqnarray*}
|\gamma'(t)|&=&\sqrt{(\sin(t)+t\cos(t)-\sin(t))^{2}+(t\sin(t)-\cos(t)+\cos(t))^{2}}\\
&=&\sqrt{t^{2}\cos^{2}(t)+t^{2}\sin^{2}(t)}\\
&=&\sqrt{t^{2}(\cos^{2}(t)+\sin^{2}(t))}\\
&=&\sqrt{t^{2}}, \quad \text{since that} \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}: \quad \cos^{2}(x)+\sin^{2}(x)=1.
\end{eqnarray*}

Finally, you need calculate $$\ell(\gamma(t))=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}|\gamma'(t)|dt.$$

Comment: Thank you so much for that response it's really helpful, if possible could you explain the final calculation? That's the part I was initially struggling with?

Comment: Note that you have $\sin t-\sin t=0$ and similar for $\cos$. Also use $\sin^2t+\cos^2t=1$ and you will get a very simple expression for $\gamma'$

Comment: @IKSmith I added more details on what you requested.

Comment: That's brilliant thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.